# xml spring for android with gradle

Tags: android, xml, spring, rest

Hi I search all over the Internet but I didn't found any grandle dependencies for new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter() I use it with maven in pom.xml file. Can I use it with grandle?

My pom is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-consuming-rest-xml-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>gs-consuming-rest-xml-android</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In gradle I try to use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.georgiadis.weatherfirstrest"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
    }
```

When I make build I take:

```
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

Comment: I get the "Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3..." when using "compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'", but not when I compile it from the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to

```
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit-simple-xml:1.5.0'
```

It works for me. The cause is that your simple-xml jar version is too high.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the code below in your build.gradle file. It work for me:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

I also answer the question: [Can not run application below lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049735/can-not-run-application-below-lollipop)