# Can not run application below lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am working with android studio .My application working fine in lollipop devices but when i run application in below lollipop devices it gives me given below error message.   I have also tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443942/xml-spring-for-android-with-grandle)  answer

> In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change  the
>   class packages
>           Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for release as it may be     conflicting with the internal version provided by
>   Android.
>                In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>           Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

My build.gradle is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile project(':library')

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.5'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.4.2'

    //For XMPP
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'
    // Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
    // Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats, …)
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0'
    // Optional for XMPP extensions support
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    /*  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1"
            // Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
            compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1"
            // Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats, …)
            compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0-rc1"
            // Optional for XMPP extensions support
            compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0-rc1"
            compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-alpha6"*/

}
```

Answer (score 17):

you can add the code below in your build.gradle file. It work for me:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Comment: 10x m8, u have saved me!
for some reason for android adding excluse in compile() dep for just one dep is not working probably because it's excluded from test configurations and others... this makes sure it will be removed from all.

Comment: @sondt87 What is creating issue here and how your solution solved this?