# Android Studio Gradle build issue(Unable to run project)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have just updated my Android Studio to latest version 2.2.2.After that need to update gradle.But after updating both I am unable to run my project which previously run very well.

Below is gradle log error:-

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for
>   productionDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for
>   productionRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for
>   stagingDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for
>   stagingRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>
> Warning:Conflict with dependency
>   'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'. Resolved versions for app
>   (23.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'.
>   Resolved versions for app (25.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> Warning:Conflict with dependency
>   'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'. Resolved versions for app
>   (23.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'.
>   Resolved versions for app (25.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> **Error:Execution failed for task**
>   **':app:prepareStagingDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.Dependency Error. See console for details.**

And Heres is My Build.gradle file for reference:-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId 'com.qa.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 28
        versionName '3.5'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 28
            versionName '3.5'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        staging {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 28
            versionName '3.5'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.0.2'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile project(':library')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
    compile project(':rate-me')
    compile project(':volleyNew')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @vishnumm93 it is bad advice. You should *resolve* the version conflict, not *avoid*.

Comment: @Anil check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049735/can-not-run-application-below-lollipop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the solution should be to add the following line to dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
```

Also you should align support libraries versions.
In your case all of them should be **25.0.0**

Here is similar question: [Resolved versions for app (22.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ)

**UPDATE:**
To make dependency control easier, you can define variable in which you can store current support libraries version.

So, your dependency block should be the following:

```
def support_version = '25.0.0'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    // support libraries that should have the same version
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"

    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':rate-me')
    compile project(':volleyNew')

    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
}
```

Read more: [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html), [Resolving conflicts between main and test APK](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Resolving-conflicts-between-main-and-test-APK)

Comment: I have added above two lines but result is same like above.

Comment: So I also need to change support version to 25.0.0

Comment: @Anil I have updated the answer. After that rebuild your project

Comment: So  I think we must have to keep dependencies and testing dependencies same right?

Comment: @Anil you are absolutely rigth

Comment: @Anil Also `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')` is redundant because _YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar_ is already added in this line: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Yup,I will change it now. Thanks

Comment: I have change `def support_version = '25.0.0'`  to `22.2.0` but it again gives same app conflict issue. I am unable to understand why this happens,any hint/solution is great for me.

Comment: Yes,previously it was resolved,but when support _version changed to 22.0.1 it's again give the same app conflict error