# Warning after including Smack library: "Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting..."

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

After adding the smack library for android i have two warnings in android console of the smack

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as
>   it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for release as
>   it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

So, can any one explain to me that how can i get rid of the warning i am getting in the android console.

Comment: Hey I need your help, I am also new to smack

Comment: yes tell..actually me too is new but if i can help, i will surely help you...

Comment: can you tell me reference links for tutorials articles? or source codes sample]

Comment: you must have implement 1 to 1 chat right?

Comment: ya I have to implement 1 to 1 chat using smack library....You can use smack library 4.2.0 - https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack

Comment: http://www.blikoon.com/tutorials/android-smack-xmpp-introductionbuilding-a-simple-client

Comment: yes I have used this both but the tutorial is for smack 4.1

Comment: You can go through the main documentation given in the GitHub

Comment: yes I have developed a sample thanks

Comment: @user3475052 i am struck with the 1to1 chat. can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718464/not-able-to-send-message-in-real-time-using-smack

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049735/can-not-run-application-below-lollipop

Answer (score 3):

Android plugin already include the Xml Pull Parser 3rd Edition (XPP3), you need to remove the XPP3 from smack with something like this:

```
// need to add the exclude for every smack dependencies.
compile ("org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0") {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

or if you a bit lazy, you can use the following (though I'm not recommend a laziness) to remove XPP3 from all dependencies:

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```